# Kiddush Levana and Women

Tags: halacha, blessing, women, kiddush-levanah

If a women would like to say the prayer of Kiddush Levana is she allowed to say it with a brocha? (not together with men)

Comment: The Gemara (San 42) says yes but some Achronim argue. Why do you think men being there is relevant?

Comment: Chana, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your questions here! This question would be stronger if you would [edit] in why you suspect that a woman's saying K"L with a brocha may or may not be allowed, and why you're limiting the question to "not together with men." I hope you'll look around Mi Yodeya and find other information that interests you, perhaps starting with some of our nearly 300 "[tag:women]" questions.

Comment: https://otniel.org/lesson/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%99-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9089&st=&pgnum=297

Answer (score 5):

Excerpts from [this blog entry:](http://youngerlight.blogspot.com/2011/03/women-and-kiddush-levana.html)

> The gemara (Sanhedrin 42a) describing kiddush levana, states regarding
>   women:
>
> אמר ליה רב אחא לרב אשי: במערבא מברכי ברוך מחדש חדשים, אמר ליה: האי -
>   נשי דידן נמי מברכי
>
> The basic implication of the gemara seems to be that although women
>   recite a shorter beracha, they do say something. Similarly, the Meiri
>   quotes the gemara almost verbatim, and Rav Ovadiah Yosef (Shu"t Yabi'a
>   Omer OC 5:36) proves that according to the Meiri, women should say the
>   short version:
>
> ומוכח דלקושטא דמילתא הוא, שהנשים מברכות בר' הלבנה בקיצור
>
> Yet, the minhag seems to have evolved that women do not say kiddush
>   levana

Several reasons given in this article, but the two that makes most sense to me are:

> 2) Maharam Shik (Shu"t, OC #90) - When to say kiddush levana is based
>   upon figuring out the calendar, and this was a skill performed only by
>   men.
>
> 4) Magen Avrohom (OC 296:11) - Has difficulty understanding (and
>   ultimately disagrees with) the Rama that women cannot make their own
>   havdalah, but should rather hear their husbands'. However, he suggests
>   (for the Rama) that perhaps women can only perform action-mitzvos
>   which are time bound (she'haz'man g'rama), and recite the accompanying
>   berachos. But they cannot recite time-bound berachos that have no
>   action attached. Therefore, they can't say havdalah, nor should they
>   say kiddush levana.

Please refer to the link and their related sources for further explanations.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1494&st=&pgnum=65 I'm farily certain this piece by Maharam Shik is discussing why women don't say Birkat HaChammah, not Kiddush Levana.

Comment: "_Please refer to the link and their related sources for further explanations_". That may be problematic now, as I get a message saying, "This blog is open to invited readers only", when I follow the link.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Nebontzol in his B'Yitzchak Yikareh siman 426:1 he adds another reason why women are exempt from kiddush levana and that is since one is supposed to go outside to recite the bracha then ot would not be befitting since "kol kivudah bas Melech pinimah".

This also appears in Shlomas Chaim Volume 1 Simman 259 by Rav Yosef Chaim Zonnenfeld, and שו"ת אפרקסתא דעניא Simman 22 (both brought by Minchas Asher Shemos 15:2)

The Mishna Brurah notes that although most mitzvos that are a zman grma may be perfromed by women and a bracha can be recited (minhag ashkanaz only), he brings from the Magen Avraham who quotes the Shelagh that kiddush levana is different since women caused the moon to be deficient .

Comment: Why shouldn't they just say it from inside then? I don't understand

Comment: Then it would only be done in a bedieved fashion, could be that its better not to do a mitzvah bedieved if one isnt commanded.

Comment: Is being outside such a fundamental part of the mitzva? It's just a custom, no? How can a custom affect fundamental obligation?

Comment: The mitzvah in pure halacha seems to be a reshus,but since there are other factors then its better not to get involved in the first place,just like teffilin which tech they can do but dont because of nikyas

Comment: Is a bracha on lightning reshus? What are you talking about? And why do we allow men who can't go outside to say it inside if it's better to not get involved with questions about a reshus?

Comment: for women kiddush levana is a reshus,for men its nit so clear,there is a whole discussion if kiddush levanah is a birkas hamitzvah or not...